# pandas unravel list to columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am quite new to pandas, and I have a numpy list looking like so:

```
something=[10,20,30,40,50]
```

When I convert it to a pandas dataframe hgowever, I have the entire list as one element:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'something': something, \
                          'something2': something2}, \
                          columns=['something', 'something2'])
```

and I get:

```
   something
0 [10,20,30,40,50]
```

What I would like is:

```
  0  1  2  3  4
0 10 20 30 40 50
```

i.e list elements as individual columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using **[`pd.Dataframe.from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html):**

```
In [323]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([something])

In [324]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[324]: 
    0   1   2   3   4
0  10  20  30  40  50
```

For multiple lists, you can simply do this:

```
In [337]: something2 = [101,201,301,401,501]                                                                                                                                                                  

In [338]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([something, something2])                                                                                                                                           

In [339]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[339]: 
     0    1    2    3    4
0   10   20   30   40   50
1  101  201  301  401  501
```

**EDIT:** **After OP's comment**

If you want all lists to be creating multiple columns, you can try this:

```
In [349]: something                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[349]: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

In [350]: something2                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[350]: [101, 201, 301, 401, 501]

In [351]: something.extend(something2) 

In [353]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([something])                                                                                                                                                       

In [354]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[354]: 
    0   1   2   3   4    5    6    7    8    9
0  10  20  30  40  50  101  201  301  401  501
```

Answer (score 1):

[pandas dataframe from dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) could help:

```
something=[10,20,30,40,50]
something2 = [25,30,22,1,5]
data = {'something':something,'something2':something2}

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,orient='index')

             0  1   2   3   4
something   10  20  30  40  50
something2  25  30  22  1   5
```

If you don't care for the indexes, and want them to be integers, [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) should suffice:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,orient='index').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing dictionary in Dataframe then by default, pandas treat the key as a column, you don't need to give columns name again, unless if you want different column names.

I tried following example:

```
import pandas as pd
something1=[10,20,30,40,50]
something2=[101,201,301,401,501]

pd.DataFrame([something1,something2])
```

**Output**

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   10  20  30  40  50
1   101 201 301 401 501
```

let me know if this works for you or not.